# Facebook comments shows warning "site unreachable" but still works

Tags: facebook, comments

I'm developing a site implementing "facebook comments".  One particular feature of the site is that I plan to have many pages implementing "facebook comments", which are generated automatically through server-side programming.

In theory this should be no problem...    I included the following javascript code that was generated for me:

```
(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=MY_APP_ID";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

The Html tag I included is the following:

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="www.myurl.com/user/{{user.id}}" data-num-posts="20" data-width="500"></div>
```

Regarding the above, you'll note that I'm using python-django, so there is a server-side variable within the double curly brackets. This allows me to have the same functionality on many automatically generated pages.

Everthing seems to be working perfectly.  Every individual page has its own respective implementation of facebook comments....  EXCEPT, I'm getting this annoying warning message "Warning: (MY URL) is unreachable."  Obviously it IS being reached because it's working properly!  So, why is it showing the warning message, and how do I get rid of it?

I tried adding the whole slew of meta properties, but no effect:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML+RDFa 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-rdfa-2.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#"
  xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" version="XHTML+RDFa 1.1">

<head>
<meta property="fb:admins" content="<MY_FB_ID>" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="bowlofgoals" />
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="<MY_APP_ID>" />
<meta property="og:title" content="Bowl of Goals"/>
<meta property="og:type" content="website"/>
<meta property="og:url" content="<URL>"/>
<meta property="fb:moderator" content="<MY_FB_ID>" />
```

Also, please note that I have also implemented facebook connect in the root folder of the site.  So, my "Site URL" in my app setting is the root folder, not the sub-pages where the facebook comments is implemented.

All the functionality is working perfectly....  so what should I do to get rid of that annoying warning message?

Thank you very much for any guidance you can offer on this.

Mark

Comment: Have you tested your url in Facebook debugger? http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Comment: Yes, and I received the following "Errors That Must Be Fixed"--
    "Missing Required Property: The og:url property is required, but not present.
Missing Required Property: The og:type property is required, but not present.
Missing Required Property: The og:title property is required, but not present."    

But as you see, I have added all those properties in the head section.  Is there another way that there properties are to be added?  Thanks.

Comment: Is your og:url tag pointing to a URL Other than the one the comments plugin is on? If so, the url you're redirecting facebook to needs to have tags too

Answer (score 1):

Consider checking your page for javascript errors. I had the exact same problem as you did and no matter what tags I added, no matter what I did, the plugin wouldn't work.

After taking a closer look in Firebug I noticed I had one javascript error caused by some slider script in my template. Removed that script and everything works like a charm now.

I assume that error was breaking all my javascript including Facebook's and that's why the plugin didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I got rid of that error by changing the **data-href** to the value that I set in **Website with Facebook Login Site URL**. So I have http://domain.org/contest/ in my Site url and my **data-href** to http://domain.org/contest

But I do have the same issue as you where my comments plugin is in a bunch of pages where the url is dynamic so something like http://domain.org/contest/id/13131 or  http://domain.org/contest/id/4848 but I cant put either one of those urls in my **data-href**. I have to put http://domain.org/contest instead in order to get rid of that error.